# JPanel flickering

Tags: java, swing, jframe, rendering

currently I am creating a custom `JFrame` with a custom `JPanel`. Rendering the `JFrame` works without flickering, but when I am rendering a custom `JPanel the components flicker. My code:

My code for painting the `JFrame`:

```
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Dimension d = getSize();
    Graphics og = g;
    g = b.getGraphics();
    //background
    g.setColor(SConstants.ct.FRAME_BACKGROUND());
    g.fillRect(SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_WIDTH(), SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_HEIGHT(), d.width - SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_WIDTH(), d.height - SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_WIDTH());

    //frame
    if(isFocused()){
        g.setColor(SConstants.ct.FRAME_FOCUSED_FRAME());
    }else{
        g.setColor(SConstants.ct.FRAME_UNFOCUSED_FRAME());
    }
    //top
    g.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_HEIGHT());
    //left
    g.fillRect(0, 0, SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_WIDTH(), d.height);
    //bottom
    g.fillRect(0, d.height - SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_WIDTH(), d.width, SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_WIDTH());
    //right
    g.fillRect(d.width - SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_WIDTH(), 0, SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_WIDTH(), d.height);

    //icon
    if(getIconImage() != null)
        g.drawImage(getIconImage(), 15, SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_HEIGHT() / 2 - getIconImage().getHeight(null) / 2, null);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setFont(SConstants.ct.FRAME_FONT());
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.drawString(getTitle(), d.width / 2 - g2d.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(getTitle()) / 2, SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_HEIGHT() / 2 - g2d.getFontMetrics().getHeight() / 2 + g2d.getFontMetrics().getAscent());
    getContentPane().paint(og);
    og.drawImage(b, 0, 0, null);
}
```

I am setting the `contentPane` like this:

```
getRootPane().setLayout(null);
    SPanel cp = new SPanel();
    cp.setBounds(SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_WIDTH(), SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_HEIGHT(), getWidth() - SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_WIDTH() * 2, getHeight() - SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_HEIGHT() - SConstants.ct.FRAME_FRAME_WIDTH());
    setContentPane(cp);
```

The `SPanel` is like this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    paintComponent(g);
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
//paintComponents(g);
    for(Component c : getComponents())
        c.paint(g);
}
```

I am rendering a `SLabel` like this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.drawString(text, getX() + SConstants.ct.LABEL_SPACING_HORIZONTAL(), getY());
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    Rectangle2D d = getGraphics().getFontMetrics(SConstants.ct.LABEL_FONT()).getStringBounds(text, getGraphics());
    int w = (int)(d.getWidth() + SConstants.ct.LABEL_SPACING_HORIZONTAL() * 2);
    int h = (int)(d.getHeight() + SConstants.ct.LABEL_SPACING_VERTICAL() * 2);
    return new Dimension(w, h);
}
```

Runnable example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8czlxc22-xqOHlPdUZxV2dkMjQ/edit?usp=sharing

Anyone know why the `SLabel` is flickering?

Comment: Why are you painting the `Components` mannually?  They have there own painting process.  You are perfoming a double painting action, as components can be painted by `paintComponents` or instructed to paint themselves by the `RepaintManager` - You DO NOT control the painting process.  You've broken the paint chain on several occasions.  None of what you've provided makes sense and frankly, you shouldn't be doing it

Comment: Running paint components does not even show the label.

Comment: What does that mean?  Did you actually add `SLabel` to one of the containers?  Is `SLabel` a `JComponent` of some kind?

Comment: SLabel is an Component.

Comment: Before you start screwing with the painting chain, take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and understand how the process actually works...

Comment: Did you add any of these components to `SPanel`?  Do you understand how components are suppose to be managed?  A component is more than just a "painted" image on the screen, in order to be interactive, they need to be registered into the system and attached to a native peer, none of which you seem to have done...

Comment: I have added the SLabel via SFrame.add(lbl)

Comment: You've also replaced the content pane, Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: If you've added `SLabel` to the container, then why do you need `SPanel` to paint the components?  `SPanel` (and the `RepaintManager`) already take care of this, you've not answered the underlying issue of "Why?"

Comment: Also, normally, `paint` WILL call `paintComponent`, because you've decided that the normal process isn't good enough for you, you've broken the underlying, default, double buffering support provided by Swing based components

Comment: You seem to be trying to "skin" or provide your own look and feel...This isn't the way to achieve this.  You might like to take a look at [Modifying the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html)

Comment: *"I edited the answer with a runnable. Run SMain.class "*  None of those uncompilable code snippets are runnable.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't seem to have an understanding of how Swing works or how painting in Swing/AWT works...

### SMain...

This...

```
public class SMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //...
        while(true){
            sf.repaint();
            Thread.sleep((int)(1000.0 / 24.0));
        }
    }
}
```

Is a bad idea...Swing uses a passive rendering model, meaning that updates occur when they are required, seen as you don't seem to be making changes to the state of the UI, this is just adding more pressure onto your system.

It could also, if called properly, prevent your UI from updating ever.

---

### SFrame...

```
getRootPane().setLayout(null);
```

Why?  Just why?  The `JRootPane` has it's own layout management process that ensures that the `contentPane` is provided all the space within the containing frame minus space for the menu bar if provided, which you've not provided so, yeah, default implementation would allow the `contentPane` to occupy all the available space...

`setSize` may be called a number of times in a row, it would be better to simply invalidate `b` (setting it to `null`) and create it only when required, (when `paint` is called), but this begs the question of why?

Why not just allow the content pane to do this for you...

`pack` would automatically resize the `contentPane`, if you would actually let the `JRootPane` do it's job...

`paint` does a number of important jobs and you've circumvented most of them, this will cause you no end of problems and weridness....

Case in point, you don't translate the `Graphics` context before you try and paint the content pane, this means that it's possible for the contents of the content paint to paint over what you have painted (ie the title).

You would be better of using...

- The content pane as it is, adding the title to the `BorderLayout.NORTH` position and the remaining content, wrapped in another container to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position of default `contentPane`
- Implementing your own `JRootPane` to provide the layout you want, using separate components for the title and content
- Implementing your own Look and Feel delegate for the `JFrame` and painting the borders yourself
- Using a `EmptyBorder` on the `contentPane` to provide space for the title...
- Just about anything else then what you have done...

Beware, `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener` may be blocked by components higher in the container hierarchy which implement either or both of those interfaces

---

### SPanel...

`paint` does a lot of important work, including, but not limited to, painting the component, border and components (as well as implementing double buffering), but you've decided to circumvent them all and do your own thing...

`paintComponent` is suppose to paint the background of the component, not it's children.  This is already done by `paint` and `paintChildren` and `paintComponents`

A child component may also be painted independently of it's parent...

---

### SComponent...

Beware, `Component` is a heavyweight (AWT) component and it's painting requirements are different from those of lightweight (Swing) components, and in fact, you should avoid adding heavy weight components to light weight containers....

`Component` already defines `paint(Graphics)`...

Heavyweight components are also not double buffered by default...this means that there updates can cause flickering...hence your problem...

"But I've double buffered the frame"...sorry to disappoint you, but components can be and are typically, painted independently of their parents, so they may not be painted as part of the parents update...

---

### Conclusions...

You don't seem to have an understanding of how painting works in AWT/Swing.  Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details...

You also don't seem to understand of the differences between Swing and AWT.  While Swing sits on top of AWT, it has it's own framework requirements which differ from AWT and some significate ways...

You seem to be trying to implement you own framework...why, I have no idea, obviously the last 20+ years of development on Swing and AWT aren't good enough or something...

You might consider having a look at [Modifying the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) and using the UI delegate API to implement what you are trying to do...

You have two choices, you can either, learn to understand how the current framework (Swing/AWT) works and work within it to achieve your goals or spend the rest of your life chasing weirdness, unexplainable problems and bugs.

You could also consider having a look at [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm#JFXST784) which allows you to modify the look and feel via CSS...